# Is there an English word for a period of 10000 years?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for a period of 10000 years, similar to how *millennium* represents 1000 years. The closest match I came up with was *myriaannum* from [*myria-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myria-) and [*annum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annus#Latin). However, the metric prefix *myria-* is [no longer used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myria-), and in common language, a [*myriad*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myriad) refers to an indefinitely large number.

*The Old Man of the Mountain was formed a myriaannum ago by glaciers.*

Is there a more commonly used word for this or is *myriaannum* my best option?

Comment: I know I could easily use "ten millennia" in the given example, but I am more interested if there is actually a word for this.

Comment: There is no more "Old Man of the Mountain." He collapsed a lustrum ago.

Comment: Over a triskaidekannum ago in fact =/

Comment: Am I getting that old?

Comment: The shortest geologic time scale I could find is a *chron* (http://palaeos.com/timescale/timeunits.html) but that is still on the order of a million years.

Comment: There are some geological words, but they are not common.

Comment: Because of some of the research I do, it would often be convenient to use a plural for multiples of 10,000 years (like "tens of years", "hundreds of years", "thousands of years" or "millennia").  However, even if there was an acceptable word for 10,000 years, I don't think I could use it since my readers wouldn't know it. :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no more commonly used word for a period of 10000 years. But I would also advise against using *myriaannum*; it does not look especially well-formed to me as a classical compound (it combines Greek *myria-* and Latin *annum*), and the prefix "myria-" seems to be obsolete in scientific compounds (like [*mega-annum*](http://thecommonroom.yuku.com/topic/3601/Does-anyone-know-if-a-period-of-10000-years#.V1tR88tlxDE)). In my opinion, it's best to just go with

> The Old Man of the Mountain was formed ten millenia ago by glaciers.

Your question, and vickyace's answer, both mention the Greek root *myria*- which was used with the meaning "ten thousand." But I cannot find any English word derived from this (aside from the aforementioned *myriaannum*) with the specific meaning "a period of ten thousand years."

I found a Math Forum thread about this topic: [Year 10,000?](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=54276) There were lots of miscellaneous suggestions for neologisms of unclear validity, but among these I found the following interesting information in a post by Patrick T. Wahl:

> The Greek word "myrioi" for 10,000 is the source of "myrietes" and
>   "myrieteris," which mean "a period of 10,000 years." Similarly, there
>   is "chilieteris," a period of 1,000 years, which uses the "chili-"
>   prefix that became our "kilo-." By the way, there's a very long word
>   for a myriad of myriads = 10^8 in Greek. Nothing like these spellings
>   seems to have entered English.
>
> Classical Latin seems to have had a wealth of "-ennium" words,
>   including some that I didn't suspect ( like triennium, tricennium,
>   tricentennium for periods of 3, 30 and 300 years respectively.) The
>   word "millenium" is the biggest I found. It appears that a modifier
>   got stuck on the front if there was more than a thousand of anything.
>   Something like "decei millenii" for ten millenia seems to be what they
>   used. [...]
>
> Consulting the Oxford English Dictionary, I found no word for "10,000
>   years" that survived into English. ( Particularly NOT "myriennium" or
>   "myriayore": those are not in the O.E.D. ) I was surprised to find the
>   Greek "chili-" word above as the English word "chiliad." It means "a
>   group of 1000," but also "1000 years." Might "myriad" have the
>   alternate meaning, too? Only a scholar can say, and the O.E.D. gave no
>   citation for such a use.

The entry for [μυριετής](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dmurieth%2Fs) *myrietḗs* in Liddell, Scott, and Jones' *Greek-English Lexicon* confirms that it was used to refer to 10,000-year periods. It seems to have been an adjective rather than a noun.

Comment: _Μῡριετής_ is a fairly straightforward [bahuvrihi compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahuvrihi) and thus primarily usable as an adjective (although the head, _ἔτος_, is a noun). It literally means ‘having 10,000 years’.

Answer (score 2):

I call it **myriad years**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad)

> the number 10000

Comment: Lovely word with a precise meaning I didn't know.  Thank you.  The problem is that 'myriad' also stands for  '...*countless elements, aspects, phases, etc.; innumerable, uncountable* (OED)' (the only sense I knew, until now).

Comment: -1 Would anyone say "century years" or even "decade years"?  *This building is over two centuries old*; *About a decade ago I gave up smoking*; *Almost two millennia have passed since the birth of Christ* (the word "years" is not needed)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "myriad" can be used as a noun or as an adjective; either "myriad years" or "a myriad of years" is acceptable.

Comment: @sumelic if the OP edits his answer, I'll reverse my downvote. I still don't like the suggestion though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm seriously asking here. How would that edit go? Should I incorporate what *sumelic* said?

Comment: You can add just an extra space, and that would be suffice. Do what you think will support your answer. HINT I'd start by looking in the wiki article and adding a few citations.

Comment: @Mari-Lou "Myriad" here is not equivalent to "century"; it's equivalent to "hundred." So you can say "myriad years" as you would say "hundred years."

Answer (score 2):

I would call a 10 millennia time span a decamillennium.

Comment: Why the hyphen?

Comment: @Lawrence I give up. Why? … I'll remove the super-fluous hyphen. I did it to help the readability for the "deca-millennium" suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Banzai may refer to: A traditional Japanese exclamation meaning "ten thousand years" of long life.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzai

It's not originally English, but lots of English isn't, either.

Comment: Considering the actual usage of banzai in English (as an exclamation) I'm not sure that this would be interpreted as intended by the average English speaker.

Comment: While true, *banzai* and the similar *wànsui* in Chinese are often used to indicate an arbitrarily large number, similar to the way English speakers would say "May you live a thousand years". This is due to the largest distinct number being 10000 in their numbering systems